# Serial port on linux in VirtualBox filters out 0x11 from data stream

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, virtualbox

I don't know if this problem is because of VirtualBox or because of the serial port configuration.  I'm testing a program that interacts with a particular piece of hardware over a serial port.  Everything is generally working fine, but in the data stream received from the device, some bytes are not received properly. Specifically 0x11, 0x13 are missing, and 0x0d is received as 0x0a.  I have a serial sniffer program watching the serial port and the byte is seen there, but it's not seen in my program that's running in a VirtualBox linux machine.  I need to see all binary bytes with no flow control.  Here's how I'm opening the serial port:

```
int openPort( char* portname )
{
  int fd;

  fd = open( portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );
  if ( fd == -1 )
  {
      perror( "openPort():" );
      printf( "Unable to open %s\n", portname );
  }
  else
  {
      fcntl( fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC );

      struct termios my_termios;
      struct termios new_termios;

      tcgetattr( fd, &termios_save );
      tcgetattr( fd, &my_termios );
      cfsetispeed( &my_termios, B9600 );
      cfsetospeed( &my_termios, B9600 );
      my_termios.c_cflag &= ~( PARENB | CSTOPB | CSIZE );
      my_termios.c_cflag |= ( CS8 | CREAD );
      my_termios.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG );
      my_termios.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
      my_termios.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
      my_termios.c_cc[VTIME] = 100;   // wait 10 seconds for a character
      tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &my_termios );
      tcgetattr( fd, &new_termios );
      if ( memcmp( &my_termios, &new_termios, sizeof( my_termios ) ) != 0 )
      {
          printf( "Error setting serial port options, aborting\n" );
          close( fd );
          fd = -1;
      }
  }

  return fd;
}
```

I've already looked at various guides to using the serial port, including [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) and this is what I've come up with.

Comment: Where is the reading code? Is the sniffer running inside the VM or on the host?

Comment: The sniffer is running on the host.  The reading code is just a read() call, and that part works fine and thus isn't relevant, so I didn't include it in the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't work fine, since it does not read what you expect. Try running some serial sniffer or terminal on the guest machine and see if the data is received fine through the VM layer.

Comment: Instead of tcsetattr(), then tcgetattr() and a memcmp(), the proper way to do this is to simply check the return code from tcsetattr().

Comment: @sawdust: No, it's not. [`tcsetattr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) followed by `tcgetattr()` and `memcmp()` **is** the proper way, because `tcsetattr()` will return success if *any* (instead of *all*) of the settings were successfully applied. See [man termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed a section in the guide.  I had originally copied my init code from some example program which I can't find now, so I don't know if they missed it also, or if I missed it in my copy.  Anyways, the problem is the setting of c_iflag, which I didn't change originally.  Adding the line:

```
my_termios.c_iflag &= ~( IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | ICRNL | INLCR | IGNCR );
```

Takes care of the issue.  Apparently software flow control and CR->NL mapping is enabled by default.

Comment: *"Apparently software flow control and CR->NL mapping is enabled by default."* -- Regardless of what is enabled by default (or currently configured), you are expected to specify every flag that is necessary for the mode you want.  There is a **cfmakeraw()** syscall for assistance in setting up non-canonical mode.

Comment: Sawdust is right. [`cfmakeraw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) is BSD-specific (meaning you need to `#define _BSD_SOURCE` before `#include`s). The [man termios(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) man page shows how to open-code it, in the *Raw mode* section.

Comment: I'm not using BSD, so that's not helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

`0x11` and `0x13` are the hex values of ASCII `XON (DC1, Ctrl-Q)` and `XOFF (DC3, Ctrl-S)` and are used to provide pacing of the data stream in applications with limited performance.

Either the host serial port, or VirtualBox, is interpreting these (or just filtering them to avoid subsequent interpretation). Set the ports to raw mode in the host machine. You don't say, but if it is some flavour of *nix, then `stty` could help.